# NSTableColumn animation

Tags: core-animation, nstableview, nstablecolumn

I want to make a table view with dynamic columns.
Similar to the one in [Ecoute](http://www.pixiapps.com/ecouteosx/images/screens/globalView-large.jpg)

I just need one column to be visible at a time. As soon as it is double clicked, the whole table view (not scroll view) should animate to the left, and the new column should appear.

I have no idea how to implement it.

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: I've sent a message to PixiApps, and here is what I got:

Comment: Well, if you can't just add a new column, just imagine you're dealing like on iOS.. add a new ViewController!
In Ecoute, I just use a kind of custom navigation controller that handles multiple view controllers to be stacked and resized.
It automatically calculates how many views can be viewed at once (using a protocol, of course, to know the min and, optionally, the max width for each viewController's view). It also manages mouse events like swipes, or even key events like the arrow keys, enter and escape key.

Comment: Fixed image here. http://www.pixiapps.com/ecouteosx/images/screens/globalView-large.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added a new NavigationViewController which handles multiple TableViewControllers which handle a table view. The NavigationViewController then animates between them.

It's actually pretty simple if you have the idea.